# Should I install Ubuntu as 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: system-installation

I have a ASUS X502CA-HPD11 laptop.It is i3 , 64 bit and windows 8. Which one should I choose 32 bit or 64bit for dual boot.

Comment: That depends on usage. What do you plan to do with that notebook an ubuntu?

Comment: In times past, 32 bit was better supported, so unless you really needed 64 bit or you really enjoyed tracking down bugs in things like flash player, 32 bit was the better choice. The last three versions, I've used 64 bit with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's website recommends installing the 64 bit version unless "you have an older PC with less than 2GB of memory."  That seems like solid advice to me.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop